# Elasticsearch dynamic template for all specific properties

Tags: elasticsearch

my data structure is something like this:

```
{ field: xxx, 
  field2: xxx, 
  attrs: { 
     field3: xxx, 
     field4: xxx, 
     var: { field5: xxx, 
            field6: xxx
     } 
  }
}
```

I don't know attribute names in `var`, can I use dynamic mapping (and how) to make every attribute ONLY IN attrs.var.XXX searchable (set index: true)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
PUT unknown_paths
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "stored_attrs_vars": {
          "path_match": "attrs.*.*",
          "mapping": {
            "index": true
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "no_index": {
          "path_match": "*",
          "unmatch": "attrs.*.*",
          "mapping": {
            "index": false
          }
        }
      }
      
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that if there's no actual field type, ES will still guess it for you. So even though you don't know the name of `attrs.var`, you'll probably know the types of `field5 and 6`, no?

Comment: He knows `attrs.var` so I guess you can use `attrs.var.*` instead of `attrs.*.*`, what he doesn't know is the name of the fields inside `attrs.var`

Comment: Can’t argue with that.

Comment: I don't even know the names of attrs.var. Only some where I put mapping I need.